# Nginx routing to another site

Tags: networking, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy, routing

I've setup nginx on an Amazon EC2 instance I've purchased but I am stuck with the most basic question. How would I be able to route all the requests to another remote address. Assume that you have the sites a.com and b.com. So when user makes a requests like;

- a.com/bringMeStuff -> **(it should route it to)** b.com/bringMeStuff
- a.com -> **(it should route it to)** b.com

I have tried methods like **proxy_pass**, **rewrite** but what I want to do exactly is to route all the urls to the other remote server. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Could you elaborate what do you mean by routing all URLs ? It'll be better if you explain it on HTTP level, like what you expect to see in HTTP response (`200`, `301`, `302`, etc.) when a request for http://domain1.tld/foo/bar comes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try rewrite module like this:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  a.com;
        rewrite         ^ $scheme://b.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
```

Comment: In the conf I have there is http {} defined. Should I delete it and later on add the server {} ?

Comment: you should add server{} scope inside http{} scope

Comment: I have a problem with the JSON data sending. I did not understand why but the JSON data is not being conceived by the b.com